# Fetch uniq set of multiple column values from a table in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, bigdata

I have a database table with records in below format =>
  col1(String) | col2(String) | col3(double)

col1 and col2 contains nodes with distance among them. Now i want to fetch all uniq nodes sorted by distance which is stored in col3.

Right now i am fetching all values in sorted order and finding uniq values from them. But it is taking too much of time(in hours).

```
select col1, col2 from tablex order by col3 desc
```

If this database is not the ideal way to store and query, suggest better one.

[image]

```
 expected output => 

 take pairs on the order of correlation value from
 highest to lowest =>  
  (d1, d3) -> 0.32 
  (d3, d4) -> 0.22 
  (d2, d3) -> 0.21 
  (d1, d2) -> 0.16 
  (d1, d4) -> 0.13 
  (d2, d4) -> 0.11

 -> finally merge them and return uniq ones. d1, d3, d3, d4, d2, d3, d1, d2, d1, d4, d2, d4

 -> final result :  d1, d3, d4, d2 (here i am taking the first occured one and ignoring the next)
```

Comment: could you provide some sample data & expected output please. You probably need an index on `col3`

Comment: @HaleemurAli updated question with sample dataset